# Twitter Like Pagination

Tags: jquery, twitter, pagination

Is there a jquery plugin that allows twitter like pagination, that can easily integrate with PHP, will_paginate works best with RoR.

Answer (score 2):

The effect you're looking for is called continuous scrolling. There are a number of jQuery plugins that exist in this space.

Here's one example: http://plugins.jquery.com/project/screw

Comment: I want one where you have to click on more,